# Max File Size php server

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, file-upload, size

I am using wamp as my test server and when trying to upload videos I am getting an error code 1 which is an error saying that my max file size is to small.  I changed my php.ini settings to

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.

upload_max_filesize = 700000000000000000M
```

and i changed my htacess file to say this ..

```
RewriteEngine On
php_value post_max_size 1000000000000000000M
php_value upload_max_filesize 1000000000000000000M
php_value max_execution_time 60000000000000
```

So there is plenty of room I don't understand why i still get this error .. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Are you sure you are editing the right php.ini? The one shown when you call `phpinfo()` in a PHP script?

Comment: I really genuinely hope nobody attempts to upload a file which is bigger than your listed settings here.

Comment: @Cyclone none one _has_ a file that big.

Comment: @Cyclone I want to see the logical disk that will store a file that large. *Correction* I want to *own* that device.

Comment: Don't set ludicrously high limits in php.ini. Use `-1` instead. Your 7kajillion and 10kajillions will definitely exceed max_int on 32bit phps.

Comment: Yea I am editing the right file i checked

Comment: @DaveRandom You and me and every other human on the planet wants that device :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Were you sure that you restarted Apache after you edited the php.ini file?

Apache loads the php.ini on start so if you made changes without restarting Apache the changes will not take effect.