# How to send large file size i.e more than 1 MB through AJAX POST Request?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to implement upload file through PHP and jquery ajax. I am able to do so for small files, however, when I try to upload large files it is showing "Unknown Error".
My jquery code :

```
var data = {
    data: self.parent().prev().find('img').attr('image_data'),
};
$.ajax({
            url: 'banner_data/upload_remove_files',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.msg != 'error' && self.hasClass('remove_class')) {
                    alert('File Uploaded');
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Unknown error occurred');
                }
            });
```

My PHP code:

```
if (!empty($_POST['data'])) {
    $file_location = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].
    '/pathname';
    $file_name = !empty($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
    list($type, $raw_data) = explode(';', $_POST['data']);
    list(, $raw_data) = explode(',', $raw_data);
    $raw_data = base64_decode($raw_data);
    if (file_put_contents($file_location.$file_name, $raw_data) === FALSE) {
        $msg = 'error';
    }
}
print json_encode(array(
    'msg' => $msg,
    'file_name' => $file_name
));
```

The **post_max_size** variable value is 100 MB. So, that is not the issue.
If the issue is in the payload limit exceeding for a POST Request, then how to tackle the same?

Comment: You only get `Unknown Error` as the error in the console? That's not possible.

Comment: Did you restart the server?   https://stackoverflow.com/a/11853729/2181514

Comment: Check the actual error in the console. The `Unknown error` message is coming from your own code and is not helpful at all.

Comment: Looks like there are a number of settings that need to be set, eg `upload_max_filesize ` https://stackoverflow.com/a/42731244/2181514 (and other answers to that question)

Comment: Good catch by @RoryMcCrossan - change your `error` handler to `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown); }` and check the console.

Comment: its showing "413 Request Entity Too Large" error as response in console

Comment: Then you need to adjust the correct settings - did you check answer here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42731188/php-change-max-file-size-upload/42731244#42731244

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Change Max File Size Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42731188/php-change-max-file-size-upload)

Answer (score 0):

Add `mimeType` to work with file sending using ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'banner_data/upload_remove_files',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.msg != 'error' && self.hasClass('remove_class')) {
            alert('File Uploaded');
        }
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Unknown error occurred');
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with this code please :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#your_form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
   url:"banner_data/upload_remove_files",
   method:"POST",
   data: new FormData(this),
   dataType:'JSON',
   contentType: false,
   cache: false,
   processData: false,
   success:function(data)
   {
    if(data.msg != 'error' && self.hasClass('remove_class')) {
      alert('File Uploaded');
    }
    },
   error:function(data){
    console.log(data);
    }
  })
 });

});
```

And use form like this:

```
 <form id="your_form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
 </form>
```

And About your **PHP code** :

```
// SET A DEFAULT VALUES
$msg = 'error';
$result = '';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $file = $_FILES['file'];
        $fileName = $file['name'];
        $fileTmpName = $file['tmp_name'];
        $fileSize = $file['size'];
        $fileError = $file['error'];
        $fileType = $file['type'];
        $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
        $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

        # VERIFY YOUR FILE HERE

        if ($fileError != 0) {
            $msg = "error";
        }

        # UPLOAD ...
        clearstatcache();
        $fileNewName = uniqid(true).".".$fileActualExt; // GENERATE NAME FOR THIS FILE
        $fileDestination = 'your_path/'.$fileNewName;


        if (move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination)) {
            $msg = "Good ...";
            $result = "File Path : ".$fileDestination;
        }
}

echo '['.json_encode(['msg' => $msg, 'file_name' => $result]).']';
```

And if you can't **send large file size** i.e more than 1 MB ... Just modify your `php.ini` :

```
post_max_size = 256M
upload_max_filesize = 1000M
```

Comment: I advise you to try with a file directly, upload an image for example without AJAX, and See if you get any error ...